# how to initialize a Vue.js property with an element of array type property

Tags: javascript, ajax, vue.js

I need to initialize properties: image, description, video and title with the respective fields of the first element of variants array.
I get the variants array sending an ajax request that return a json file.

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    name: '<?php echo $name ?>',
    image: '',
    description: '',
    video: '',
    title: '',
    variants: ''
  },
  methods: {
    updateAll: function(im, des, t, v) {
      this.image = im;
      this.description = des;
      this.title = t;
      this.video = v;
    },
    getQuery: function() {
      axios.get('ajaxfile.php', {
        params: {
          name: this.name
        }
      }).then(function(response) {
        app.variants = response.data;
      }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
    }
  },
  created: function() {
    this.getQuery()
  }
});
```

Comment: `variants` should be declared an array which contains the various properties of the image.

Comment: variants is composed with an ajax request and each element contains 5 fields: image, description, video and title.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not processing the json stored in `app.variants` nor are you calling the `updateAll()` method. Assuming that `app.variants` does not need any further processing, then perhaps calling `updateAll()` when you receive data through the ajax request would be your best solution.

Comment: upadateAll() is just a method called from html on a click event and it works correctly. I need initialize the data properties without need to trigger the click event. I need to do something like this: image: variants[0].image,   description: variants[0].description.. and so on

Answer (score 0):

I this case I would simply use the updateAll() method you have. something like this:

```
  }).then(function(response) {
    app.variants = response.data;
this.updateAll(app.variants[0].image, app.variants[0].description, app.variants[0].title, app.variants[0].video)
  }).catch(function(error) {
```

but.. it's not that clean :)

Comment: I've already tried this solution but i don't know why it doesn't work. Thanks anyway for the reply.

Comment: Could you try and post a screenshot of the errors in your log?